# Dynamical ms sql query

Tags: sql-server

I have problems with my dynamical ms sql query. Can someone help me. Here is my code. Problem is inside the OPENQUERY, near '1033'

```
DECLARE @sql nvarchar(max);
    DECLARE @server nvarchar(255) = (SELECT [Value] FROM [WarehouseMgmt].[SyncConfig] WHERE [Key] = 'ReportServerLinkedServer')
    DECLARE @database nvarchar(255) = (SELECT [Value] FROM [WarehouseMgmt].[SyncConfig] WHERE [Key] = 'ReportServerDatabase')




 SET @sql = 'MERGE [WarehouseMgmt].[DimReportServerReports] AS DRSR
    USING (SELECT ItemId,Name FROM OPENQUERY('+@server+',''SELECT ItemId,Name FROM '+@database+'.[dbo].[Catalog] WHERE Type=2 AND Name NOT LIKE ''1033%'' AND Path NOT LIKE ''/Reports/%Subs'')   
     ) AS CATALOG
    ON (DRSR.[SourceOrigId] = [Catalog].[ItemId])
    WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET  THEN 
        INSERT 
        (
            [SourceOrigId],
            [ReportName],
            SyncExecId
        )
        VALUES 
        (
            [Catalog].[ItemId],
            ISNULL([Catalog].[Name],''<UNKNOWN>''),
            @SyncExecId
        )
    OUTPUT  
            [Catalog].[ItemId],
            [Catalog].[Name]
    INTO #NewReportServerReports;'

    EXEC sp_executesql @sql,N'@SyncExecId int',@SyncExecId
```

Error code is:

> Msg 50000, Level 11, State 1, Procedure WriteJobLog, Line 101 Error
>   writing job log: Line #90: [ERR]  #2: Incorrect syntax near '1033'.

Comment: could you post the error generated by sql..

Comment: You are missing the closing `'` (single quote)for the open query at the end

Comment: where ? near which character ?

Comment: after `Subs''` you need one more quote

Comment: WHERE Type=2 AND Name NOT LIKE ''1033%'' AND Path NOT LIKE ''/Reports/%Subs'' '') This is not the solution !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Added few `quotes`. Try this.

```
 SET @sql = 'MERGE [WarehouseMgmt].[DimReportServerReports] AS DRSR
    USING (SELECT ItemId,Name FROM OPENQUERY('+@server+',''SELECT ItemId,Name FROM '+@database+'.[dbo].[Catalog] WHERE 
    Type=2 AND Name NOT LIKE ''''1033%'''' AND Path NOT LIKE ''''/Reports/%Subs'''''')   
     ) AS CATALOG
    ON (DRSR.[SourceOrigId] = [Catalog].[ItemId])
    WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET  THEN 
        INSERT 
        (
            [SourceOrigId],
            [ReportName],
            SyncExecId
        )
        VALUES 
        (
            [Catalog].[ItemId],
            ISNULL([Catalog].[Name],''<UNKNOWN>''),
            @SyncExecId
        )
    OUTPUT  
            [Catalog].[ItemId],
            [Catalog].[Name]
    INTO #NewReportServerReports;'
    --print @sql
    EXEC sp_executesql @sql,N'@SyncExecId int',@SyncExecId
```